# How to invoke an initscript after network connection?

Tags: bash, embedded-linux, sysv

I have a `initscript` which I would like to execute only after network connection establishment. Becasue the init script will invoke a `curl` call. I beleive this is rather straightforward with `systemd` `After=network-online.target`. But, how can I do this with `sysvinit`? The linux is a custom built using `yocto`. There is no `systemd` available.

structure of initscript:

```
#!/bin/bash
# description: Description comes here....

# Source function library.
. /etc/init.d/functions

start() {
    # code to start app comes here
    make curl call
}

stop() {
    # code to stop app comes here 
    # example: killproc program_name

}

case "$1" in 
    start)
       start
       ;;
    stop)
       stop
       ;;
    restart)
       stop
       start
       ;;
    *)
       echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
esac

exit 0
```

P.S: Please let me know if any info is missing

Comment: If I recall correctly, the init scripts in /etc/init.d are called in the order specified by the numbers in the names of the script.  You need to make sure your script is called after the network startup.

Comment: How can I check these numbers? Is there any default number for networking?

Comment: https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_1.2.0/gLSB/initscrcomconv.html

Comment: It's been too long since I have been using systemd and have forgotten so much!  Thank you for forcing me into a quick doc refresh, I like the nostalgia!  The number I was thinking of are in the names of the symbolic links to the script in `/etc/rd?.d`.  Each runlevel uses the order provided by the names of those links.  I think it is purely lexicographic, and the convention is to use integer names.

Comment: So if your script is `/etc/init.d/myservice` and you want it to start in runlevel n, check the name of the link for the  networking service `/etc/rcn.d`, and create a link to your script there with the appropriate name.  But don't do that.  Instead, follow the LSB conventions for the comment and use the tooling to install the links.

Comment: So, if I include `Required-Start: $network` in LSB header, then my script will be executed after networking service, right?

Comment: sort of.  It looks like the whole setup is still a mess, with distributions using bespoke tooling to install the init scripts.  lsb suggests using `install_initd`, but whether or not that script is available is a different question.  Looks like it might be easier to do it the old -fashioned way and just make the link yourself.